# Can the term «shadow» pertain to anything else than light?

Tags: visible-light, soft-question, terminology, particle-physics, shadow

Can the term [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_%28disambiguation%29) pertain to anything else than light? Feel free to interpret this question in the widest sense possible.

Comment: The link Qmechanic added answers your question. I do not see a question about physics here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the usage of an english word. It might be better posed on EL&U.SE

Answer (score 6):

Yes! Any beam that is blocked by an object will basically make a shadow. For example, the IceCube detector can see the moon's [cosmic ray shadow](http://icecube.wisc.edu/news/view/131).

Comment: Exellent, I wish I'd thought of that one!

Answer (score 2):

For example, acoustic shadow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_shadow ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example a [Crookes tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_tube) shows an electron shadow. The area I live (Chester, UK) is in a [rain shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the term "shadow" can refer also to something or (dare I say) someone that is dark, shady, inconspicuous, etc. One can also use it as a verb; to shadow someone is to follow them closely. Like "I'm having the new guy shadow me for a while until he learns how to do everything".

Comment: I was hesitant to use this definition at first, but the question says "feel free to interpret this question in the widest sense possible". I think I've succeeded at that